# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN for single website

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku, gunicorn, amazon-route53

I created [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295294/django-hsts-wsgi-site-cannot-be-reached?noredirect=1) earlier but was told that it is a DNS issue as apposed to an issue with HSTS. Regardless, here is what I need help troubleshooting:

**Issue**:
A single site (one that I own), is showing `server DNS address could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` when I try to connect to it via chrome, firefox, or safari. I can however connect to it via Tor Browser. I can also verify that the address resolves correctly using [mxtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/supertoolmobile.aspx). I also am not able to connect via two other computers and two other phones. I also am not able to connect via a different WIFI connection or personal hotspot via my phone. Curl and Host via the command line are also not able to get a response.

**What I've tried**:
As I said above, I've tried different internet connections and computers. I've also tried flushing my DNS cache and pointing to another DNS server.

Having said that, I am not sure how else to trouble shoot this. The only change I made to the web app was to add HSTS headers, hence why I created the [earlier posing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295294/django-hsts-wsgi-site-cannot-be-reached?noredirect=1). Please let me know what other information I can provide. Otherwise, here are some details about the site itself:

Other information about my stack:

- Django web app
- Gunicorn / WSGI server
- Hosted on Heroku - Cedar-14 stack
- DNS setup with AWS route53
- domain name registered through AWS

**EDIT**:

Possibly related: https://serverfault.com/questions/606880/how-can-i-troubleshoot-a-route-53-hosted-zone

Comment: Can you share your domain? It will become more easy for me to debug the issue?

Comment: Ok what are this name servers for? Name Server: ns14.wixdns.net
Name Server: ns15.wixdns.net
Name Server: ns-1040.awsdns-02.org did you transferred this domain to Route 53?

Comment: the wix ones are irrelevant. I just removed those. `beta.` & `www.beta.` are supposed to be pointing to a different heroku app.

Comment: Yes but they are not propagated yet so wait till they propagate once the whole DNS name servers are running through route 53 then the domains will act normal. The name server propagation takes time approx 12 hrs. All name server should serve through Route 53

Comment: The weird thing is that they've been propagated for quite some time. Everything was working great for about a month until yesterday.

Comment: But they are still showing in whois. Make sure when you delete the wix records you save the record set or they will appear again.That is the reason the domains are not acting healthy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116944/discussion-between-dperconti-and-error2007s).

Comment: I guess the domain issue is now resolved.

Comment: I'm still seeing the wix domains on my end.. :/

Comment: But the domain is working for me  beta.paylasso.com

Comment: kk. If you want you can answer the question with making sure the  Local NS matches the Parent NS list and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So from our discussion regarding the NS server records always make sure that the local NS records matches the Parent NS records.

In your case there there were 2 extra NS records associated with your domain that was the reason why your domains and sub domains were acting unhealthy. once you deleted those records the domains and sub domains were back to normal.

Answer (score 5):

I had the similar issue and was not able to open Facebook. Rest all sites were working fine. Initially, I thought Facebook blocked me as I never faced this crappy issue earlier. Later when I searched in Google, I found an article which described the DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN issue on Chrome.

I just changed my DNS server address as 8.8.8.8 (preferred) and 8.8.4.4 (alternate) and I never faced that issue again.

Reference - https://www.mobipicker.com/dns_probe_finished_nxdomain/

Answer (score 0):

you can also try to open an anon window

access the url

use it in anon mode

or

close it and it will load ok